# How to save multiple check box value in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I think it might be silly question to ask but trust me I am new to ReactJS, I want to make a logic for checkbox . Actually, I have multiple checkbox in my program I want to save multiple check box value ( if user select ) in single State or Array . I tried hard but didn't find any proper solution . could someone please help me how to solve this problem .

Thanks

Comment: Could you add any code example of what you're doing now?

Comment: Actually, currently I don't have code I want to make a logic but I am failed in making of logic. I want to store all those values which selected by user in checkbox for example if user click on multiple check box then I want to store these all values which select by user

Comment: https://medium.com/@wlodarczyk_j/handling-multiple-checkboxes-in-react-js-337863fd284e

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your code, I think the answer would be to create something like:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={this.state.active}
    onClick={this.handleClick}
/>
```

And then have the handleClick toggle a property of an object in memory (derived from state), and then call `setState` using that object, to hold all of the tickbox values in a single state property.

Comment: Can you please make a simple program in React where we can handle  these all stuff

Comment: Actually, currently I don't have code I want to make a logic but I am failed in making of logic. I want to store all those values which selected by user in checkbox for example if user click on multiple check box then I want to store these all values which select by user

Comment: @Samri - I'm not able to create an entire application for you. If you need a developer, there are lots of job platforms out there, but StackOverflow is for getting help with code that you have written yourself.
My snippet gives you the starting point for implementing a handler for multiple checkboxes.